# Form not posting one field

Tags: php, forms, post, select-options

I ran into a problem in my php/html code here, and I can't seem to locate the bug. The form seems to be posting everything except this one field, which seems to return "empty" every time.
(trying to set the variable "active" from the "select" option in the form, defaults to database value. The problem is, it's always returning to the default [database] value, regardless of the "select" option below...even after posting the form.) *Note that the database value of "active" is a 0/1 bit value. Does this affect the result?

```
php:
$active = (!empty($_REQUEST["active"]))?$_REQUEST["active"]:$row["active"];

html: 
<select class="sel" name="active" id="active">
    <option value="0" <?php echo ($active=="0"?"selected":"");?>>Not Active</option>
    <option value="1" <?php echo ($active=="1"?"selected":"");?>>Active</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also note that I have several other select options that are working properly. This is the only one not working.

Comment: If you dump the contents of `$_POST`, is the `active` key present but empty, or not present at all?

Comment: active is present, and working fine.
New development:
If I start with a value of 0 (not active), things seem to work fine. However, if I start with a value of 1 (active), I run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, `empty` will return true for the string "0", thus setting `$active` to the pre-existing value in such cases. What you maybe want instead is something like:

```
$active = (array_key_exists('active', $_REQUEST) ? (!empty($_REQUEST['active']) ? true : false) : $row['active']);
```

This will set the `$active` variable to `true` if the provided string is not considered empty (i.e. anything other than 0 or an empty string), `false` if it's present but empty, and preserve the existing value if the array key doesn't exist in the data.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me understand and works well! I really appreciate your help!